# which barcode font is used to scan 15 letter size in ,net c#

Tags: c#, fonts, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to scan barcode and show their result in .net c# application. Now, barcode scan is working verywell in my application for short word/number. But \if that barcode code/number is more then 10 or 12 then barcode font scan is not working. So, is there any barcode font was there so it can scan big number of barcode like 15 number of barcode.

Comment: The question may be not accurate. Please refer to these pages for basic barcode knowledge. [Barcode - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode), [Barcoding for Beginners & Barcode FAQ](https://www.barcodefaq.com/barcoding-for-beginners/)

Comment: Please give a specific example of what you are trying to do. Use graphics and code if possible. I can't tell if 15 refers to number of characters, height or width dimensions or font size if you are using a font. Also, what symbology (Code 39, Code 128, QR Code)?